# In a zoomable scrollview, how to determine the location of the content wrt the window?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have a zoomable `UIScrollView` which contains a custom drawn view (two circles). When the view is zoomed, I want to know where the centres of the circles lie, wrt the App's window. Consider these steps:
[image: 1. The view at 1x]

The view at 1X

[image]

The view zoomed at an arbitrary level, with the pinch focused on the first circle

[image]

The view zoomed at an arbitrary level, with the pinch focused on the top right corner
What I am meaning to ask is, if I were to lay another view containing a circle on top of the scroll view such that the circle in this view is concentric (need not be of the same size) with the smaller circle in the scroll view's view, where should the centre of the new circle be located?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using UIView's coordinate conversion methods it is not relevant that you custom view is embedded in a scroll view:

```
MyCustomCircleView *circleView;

CGPoint centerInLocalCoordinates = circleView.centerOfACircle;
CGPoint centerInWindowCoordinates = [circleView convertPoint:centerInLocalCoordinates
                                                      toView:nil];
```

Maybe window coordinates are not what you are looking for. Remember that the window's coordinate space is always in portrait orientation and with the home button at the bottom. When holding the device in landscape orientation, your coordinates are (of course) rotated.

It might be easier to convert to a superview's coordinates, for example your view controller's view's coordinate space.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. BTW, instead of passing `nil` in `toView:` I passed another view (see edit above).

Answer (score 0):

Did you draw the circles? Some combination of `scrollView.contentOffset`, `scrollView.contentSize`, and `scrollView.zoomScale` is what you want. You can walk back the translation and scaling using those values.

Comment: -1 Far too complicated. Does not take other view transforms into account. CodeBreaker asked for window coordinates, so you have to convert down to the root of the view hierarchy.

Comment: The framework method knows better about all the gory details of view transformation.

Comment: Fair. Perhaps, nonetheless, you should read [this post about downvoting](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down).

Comment: (also, good to know about passing nil to `convertPoint:toView:`. I didn't know you could do that)

Comment: Agree, downvote was hypercritical. Alas, cannot remove downvote due to questionable SO voting rules. Upvoted on unrelated answer of yours instead.

Comment: @samson That's what I was playing with for hours, but I'm not that good at geometry ;)